# How can I get unique data in different array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have 3 arrays like this,

```
var data1 = ['a','b','c'];
var data2 = ['b','c','d'];
var data3 = ['c','d','e'];
```

then I need to push unique value in to new data `var newData = [];`

I need result in my `newData` have only  `'a','b','c','d','e'` without duplicate

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unique values in an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960473/unique-values-in-an-array)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```js
    var data1 = ['a','b','c'];
    var data2 = ['b','c','d'];
    var data3 = ['c','d','e'];
    var newArr=[]
    data1.concat(data2,data3).forEach(function(a,i){
      if(newArr.indexOf(a)===-1){
      newArr.push(a)
      }
    })

console.log(newArr);
```

Answer (score 2):

Modern browser?

```
var newData = Array.from(new Set(data1.concat(data2, data3)));
```

or

```
var newData = [...new Set(data1.concat(data2, data3))];
```

Comment: Nice approach. Awesome :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this Example

```
var data1 = ['a','b','c'];
var data2 = ['b','c','d'];
var data3 = ['c','d','e'];
var finaldata = data1.concat(data2,data3);

var unique = finaldata.filter(function(elem, index, self) {
      return index == self.indexOf(elem);
});
console.log(unique);
```

Answer (score 0):

You want values from all three arrays but only unique values. That's a Set. ES2015 introduced sets, which are spec'd to use performant (log or constant time) access and checking.

```js
var data1 = ['a','b','c'];
var data2 = ['b','c','d'];
var data3 = ['c','d','e'];

const set = new Set(data1.concat(data2).concat(data3))

const nonDuplicates = [...set]

console.log(nonDuplicates)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const newData = [...new Set(data1.concat(data2, data3))];
```